# EF 4.1 Code First: "non-null value of type 'DateTime'" Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, code-first, ef-code-first

After initial dev and testing I have now pointed my MVC3 application at an existing database which contains live data.

However I am getting this error related to the field called Date1 of type "datetime".

```
The 'Date1' property on 'StaffAttachment' could not be set to a 'null' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'DateTime'.
```

Is this telling me that all rows in the date must have a date and not be null? What do I do if I dont want to set a date on specific row?

Can anyone offer advice on resolving this issue?

Thanks Paul

EDIT 1 (Posting Model)

```
public class StaffAttachment
{
    [Key]
    public int AttachmentID { get; set; }

    public int? StaffID { get; set; }

    public int? TypeID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Proof of ID")]
    public int? AttachmentTypeID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("ID Reference")]
    public string Reference1 { get; set; }

    public string Reference2 { get; set; }

    public string DateType { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Expiry Date")]
    public DateTime Date1 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Date2 { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date3 { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date4 { get; set; }

    public string AttachmentPath { get; set; }

    public int? ValidatedUserID { get; set; }

    public DateTime ValidatedDate { get; set; }

    public int? CreatedUserID { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public int? EditedUserID { get; set; }

    public DateTime EditedDate { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan TimeStamp { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public byte[] FileImage { get; set; }

    public int AttachmentSection { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: does the DB you point at have null values for `Date1`? That would explain it.

Comment: yes, there are many nulls in that field. but surely that is okay as i ticked the "allow nulls" option on the sql server 2008 column.

Comment: It's ok for SQL server, but not for your data model - your Date1 field (assuming its of type `DateTime`) does not allow nulls - `DateTime` is a value type so it can't be null.

Comment: hmm, but my proj does not compile when i set DateTime? as per my comment on your answer below. what do you suggest i do? thanks very much for your time btw :) paul

Comment: what part doesn't compile? You still seem to map to a `DateTime` somewhere instead of `DateTime?` - can you paste your model?

Answer (score 28):

> Is this telling me that all rows in
>   the date must have a date and not be
>   null? What do I do if I dont want to
>   set a date on specific row?

It looks like the DB you point at have null values for `Date1`. If you do indeed not want to set a date for all rows, just make your `Date1` property nullable:

```
public DateTime? Date1{get;set;}
```

Alternatively you can just put in a default date for all the rows that do not have a datetime set currently via SQL.

Comment: When i have "DateTime?", I get build error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.DateTime'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: @Paul Brown: Then cast it: `Date1 = (DateTime?)item.Date1`

Comment: where, in my model? sorry i am a newbie!

Comment: On this line "public DateTime? Date1{get;set;}"

Comment: could anyone please convert this to VB.net code.. I have tried Public Property Date1() As Date?

Answer (score 10):

```
public DateTime? Date1 { get; set; }
```

use this, your model needs to be told that there can be null values inside your database, otherwise it will assume there isn't.

Comment: could anyone please convert this to VB.net code.. I have tried  Public Property Date1() As Date?

Comment: This solved my problem! It actually solved another issue I was having but I looked and looked through various posts and none of the suggestions worked. Thanks.

Comment: How this answer is diff from above one posted by @BrokenGlass ?

Comment: Let's go back to the land of time in 2011 and 2012 to tell you that there is no difference, he never accepted an answer; therefore it was an open question - meaning I answered it without reading @BrokenGlass answer from the year before. Ode to be young and naive again.

Answer (score 4):

Use this :

```
public Nullable<DateTime> LoginDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Sorry, but both Nullable<DateTime> and DateTime? don't work. Are there any other solutions ?